# Elm: Html embedded in Svg bug

Tags: html, svg, textarea, elm

In Elm I'm trying to embed a Html textarea in Svg, but the textarea won't load correctly. Can someone help me?

```
svgTextarea : Model -> Html Msg
svgTextarea model =
    let
        textspace =
            textarea [ onInput ChangeSvgText ] []

        ( w, h ) =
            ( 200, 200 )
    in 
    svg
      [ width w
      , height h
      , viewBox <| "0 0 " ++ toString w ++ " " ++ toString h
      ]
      [ textspace ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Example repo: https://github.com/gitLabor8/Elm-Html-embedded-in-Svg-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `textarea` on its own is not valid SVG. You need to wrap it in a [`foreignObject`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/2.0.0/Svg#foreignObject) tag.

```elm
svgTextarea model =
    let
        textspace =
            Svg.foreignObject []
                [ textarea [ onInput ChangeSvgText ] [] ]
    ...
```

Note that `foreignObject` tags are [not supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject#Browser_compatibility).